# Creating colorpicker on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, color-picker

How to draw a colorpicker on HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Considering the thorough elaboration of your question, the answer might be: "With for loops". Can you show us what you've tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic example would be using `getImageData`: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/60/.

```
var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');

for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + 
            ((i/30*255)|0) + ',' + 
            ((j/30*255)|0) + ',' +
            '0)';

        ctx.fillRect(i * 10, j * 10, 10, 10);
    }
}

$('#cv').click(function(e) {
    // get pixel under mouse cursor
    var data = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
    alert('rgb: ' + [].slice.call(data, 0, 3).join());
});
```

Comment: I know how to extract current color, I dont know how to draw it.

Answer (score 3):

I created a solution for you on HCT.  You can see it here:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-color-picker/

The idea is to find a color picker image that you like and then draw it on the canvas.  On the mousedown event, we can get the mouse coordinates and then use the image data of the color picker image to pick out the color.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have to draw the colors manually. Then you need to listen for mouseclick in that area, and then get the color at the click position.

The biggest problem is how to draw the colors. There are a few examples in [Drawing Color Spectrums](http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=200).