# Mapping Color Space in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

So i'm trying to map color space in HTML and my knowledge is pretty much limited to CSS HTML and Javascript. I am looking for a way to construct a 2 dimensional gradient, with 2 variable along 2 vectors. My research has indicated that CSS and SVG tech only has capacity for single dimension grdaients. Or rather Linear Grads can only have a single vector. So to make up for this limitation I am using JS to iterate over the 256 changes I need so that I can get a gradient on 2 RGB color channels. So picture if you will an x-axis that is relative to for example purposes - Red and Grads from 0 to 255 and y-axis that is likewise relative - Green and Grads from 0 to 255 but with a JS iteration instead of a CSS linear-grad.

What I end up with is a beautiful representation of RGB color space !BUT! changes to the z-axis -blue channel in this example- means that I have to call on a JS function that iterates through 256 loops updating the background of 256 DOM elements with new CSS linear grads.

I am making this web-app because of the limitations that I see in current web-based color pickers a 256 step loop for each change of the Z-axis will place an unacceptable amount of computation overhead into the program.

Any Idea's for a better way to make a dual vector gradient? Perhaps I could make an app specific library for the HTML 5 canvas element??? Where I would be operating on a bitmap instead of DOM elements maybe significantly lower the processor cost-per-call?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`canvas`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-canvas-element) element for that. [Here](http://nerderg.com/Canvas+Color+Picker) [are](http://www.jswidget.com/lab/canvas-based-color-picker.html) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819034/creating-colorpicker-on-html5-canvas) [examples](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-color-picker/) [of](http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/article/html5-painting-canvas) [colorpickers](http://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-an-html5-canvas-image-color-picker/).

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to create two linear gradients, one horizontal one vertical, moving from transparent to whatever rgba colors you want. Then draw one gradient over the other on the canvas. There's kind of a catch though, I've found that canvas doesn't make very clean rgba gradients, but you can uses half transparent colors, draw the first one once, the second one twice, then the first one again and it seems to give pretty good results. You can play with it though, here's some code to work off of.

```
    var Draw = function(clr1, clr2){
        clr1 = clr1 || 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';
        clr2 = clr2 || 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';

        var bg1 = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),            
            grad1 = bg1.createLinearGradient(0, 128, 256, 128),
            grad2 = bg1.createLinearGradient(128, 0, 128, 256);

        grad1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)');
        grad1.addColorStop(1, clr1);

        grad2.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)');
        grad2.addColorStop(1, clr2);

        bg1.fillStyle = grad1;
        bg1.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);


        bg1.fillStyle = grad2;
        bg1.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
        bg1.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);

        bg1.fillStyle = grad1;
        bg1.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
    }
```

Comment: Using a very similar method I was able to make an effective overlay for HSL color space, however, I don't think it can be tweaked to produce the results I'm looking for in RGB color space. I will play with it some more and see if I can come up with something effective. If all else fails I may write a small lib for canvas with improved methods, I really think the linear grad method could benefit from 'modes' anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example showing how to create an arbitrary gradient on a canvas, with per-pixel control: http://jsfiddle.net/j85FQ/3/

[image]

```
colorField( myCanvas, 500, 500, pretty );

function colorField(canvas,width,height,colorLookup){
  var w = width-1, h = height-1;
  canvas.width  = width;
  canvas.height = height;  
  var ctx  = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      idata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,width,height),
      data  = idata.data;
  for (var x=0;x<width;++x){
    for (var y=0;y<height;++y){
      var rgba = colorLookup(x/w,y/h);
      var o = (width*y+x)*4;
      for (var i=0;i<4;++i) data[o+i] = rgba[i]*255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(idata,0,0);
}

function pretty(xPct,yPct){
  return [ xPct, yPct, xPct*(1-yPct), 1];
}
```

Comment: FWIW it takes my computer ~40ms to fill three 300×300 canvases with complex color lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I was able to work it out with the canvas element.  I used a bucket fill for the z channel value and horizontal & vertical linear gradients from 0 to 255 for x and y channels. Setting context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter" was the key I was missing.  That was the simple additive mode I needed much easier then trying to find a suitable alpha compositing method.  The following is the canvas init function I wrote.

```
    function init() {
     var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
     ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
     var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 512, 0);
     grd.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
     grd.addColorStop(1, "#FF0000");
     var grd2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 512);
     grd2.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
     grd2.addColorStop(1, "#00FF00");
     ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
     ctx.fillStyle = grd;
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
     ctx.fillStyle = grd2
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512)
  }
```