# how to make a color selection line in hmtl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a color sampler line as in the attached picture, but I don't know exactly how to do it, could someone do it or at least explain how to do it

[image]

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source of your example to see how it is done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following and You will develope your needs.

```html
<input type="color">
```

You should look example video : [Create Color Picker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIw-Nou9L9E)

Comment: I meant more how to make this color selection line

Comment: I think that you didn't search, you directly wrote your question. I'll give two links, please try to investigate your problem. 

https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-color-picker/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819034/creating-colorpicker-on-html5-canvas